# R quantstrat backtest with dollar based position sizing

Tags: r, backtesting, error

I am attempting to tweak a quantstrat based backtest but have run into an issue.

The maxPos limits are share based, and I would rather use a fixed dollar amount instead. So I've tried generating a max position based on a fixed dollar amt divided by the closing price:

```
MaxPos = 10000/Cl(OLN)
```

but this throws the following error:

```
Error in xts(cbind(maxpos, longlevels, minpos, shortlevels), order.by = as.POSIXct(timestamp)) : 
  NROW(x) must match length(order.by)
```

There is limited documentation on how to work with this package and I am really stuck on what would seem to have a simple solution.